# IE11 doesn't accept font-weights that aren't multiples of 100

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I have an app that takes in font weights such as 380 and 350 for branding purposes and these fonts work perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, when I go onto IE11, the font weights are much more bolded, seemingly adopting the font weights of other text that uses a font weight that is a multiple of 100. I went into the console and changed these font weights to 400 and it does change to a lighter text but is there any way I could get it to be exactly 350/380? I couldn't find anything useful online about this.

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about Internet Exploder. Continue making your site as awesome as possible in other browsers.

Comment: Looks like IE11 only has around 2% of market share, so not a big deal to quit supporting it. https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php  If you *really* need it exact, use an image file.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, IE11 does not support font weight variations that deviate from multiples of 100s. My suggestion would be to use a media query to change the font weight that is the closest to 350/380 for IE11. So you'll set the font weight in IE11 to 400 specifically.

```css
/* Other browsers will have font-weight of 380 */
body {
  font-weight: 380;
}

/* Target IE11 and set font-weight to 400 */
@media (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  body {
    font-weight: 400;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample using the font-weight with different value, it seems that this is the IE browser default behavior, the font weight in IE browser is a little bolder than Chrome or Edge browser's font weight. The screenshot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8fKH.png).

The font-weight value is defined discretely (using the whole multiple of 100). The value is real, and the value of an integer multiple that is not 100 is rounded to the full multiple of 100, and when you encounter a full multiple of 100, you will convert up, such as 150, to 200.

So, in my opinion, I suggest you directly change the font-weight value to 400 (You could also check previous screenshot, it seems that after rendering, they are similar).